# Create table based on the data value of another table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I try to create a new table based on the existing table. If the table value in A = 'TC' or '0', the table value in B will be '0', else the table value in B will follow the table value in A.

This is what I have tried, but I'm not sure about the logic that I code. Hopefully, someone will help me.

```
$subject = Scsj::get();
    if ($subject->teknologi_dan_sistem_maklumat=='TC'||'0') {
        $subject->teknologi_dan_sistem_maklumat=='0';
    } else {
        $subject->teknologi_dan_sistem_maklumat=='1';
    }
```

Comment: Is this code in a migration? `Scsj::get()` will produce a collection, not an individual Eloquent model.

Comment: I write this code in Controller file

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you use the equal operator to set the variable. As 1000Nettles said, `get()` will return you a collection of data. If you wish to retreive an object, use the `first()` method.

Besides, I would rewrite your code to make it smaller:

```
$subject = Scsj::first();
 $var = $subject->teknologi_dan_sistem_maklumat;
if ($var =='TC'|| $var == '0') {
    $subject->teknologi_dan_sistem_maklumat = '0';
} else {
    $subject->teknologi_dan_sistem_maklumat = '1';
}
```

**Edit:**
You are trying to make a new database record, setting the value of the old database record wont help unless you plan on updating the record.

Comment: Property [teknologi_dan_sistem_maklumat] does not exist on this collection instance. i got this error after trying your suggestion

Comment: $subject=Scsj::inRandomOrder()->first(); to get a random single data from the database or get a specific data basing on the id like this $subject=Scsj::find(1)->first();

Comment: If the record does not exist, it means that is it not an column in your database table. Please start with the basics in order to learn about databases, tables, columns and retreiving and setting data of that table.